# $d^{2}=\frac{G(\alpha_{1},...\alpha_{k},\alpha-\beta)}{G(\alpha_{1},...\alpha_{k})}$

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, determinant

In a Euclide vector space $E$ with scalar $ \left \langle ;\right \rangle$. Let $\alpha , \beta$ be two abritrary vectors and for a subspace $U \subset E$ define :

$$\beta + U = \left \{ \beta + u , u \in U \right \}$$

Prove that the distance $d$ between vector $\alpha$ and subspace $\beta + U$ satisfies the following formular :

$$d^{2}=\frac{G(\alpha_{1},...\alpha_{k},\alpha-\beta)}{G(\alpha_{1},...\alpha_{k})}$$

Here we have $\alpha_{1},...\alpha_{k}$ is a basis of $U$ and

$$G(\alpha_{1},...\alpha_{k}) =det \begin{pmatrix}  \left \langle \alpha_{1}, \alpha_{1}  \right \rangle & \left \langle \alpha_{1},\alpha_{2} \right \rangle & ... &  \left \langle \alpha_{1},\alpha_{k} \right \rangle \\  \left \langle \alpha_{2},\alpha_{1}\right \rangle & \left \langle \alpha_{2},\alpha_{2} \right \rangle & ... &  \left \langle \alpha_{2},\alpha_{k} \right \rangle\\ .& . & ... &. \\  \left \langle \alpha_{k},\alpha_{1} \right \rangle &  \left \langle \alpha_{k},\alpha_{2} \right \rangle & ... &  \left \langle \alpha_{k},\alpha_{k}\right \rangle\end{pmatrix}$$

My attempt :

Lemma : For two vector $\alpha , \beta$ and subspace $U$ , if $\alpha - \beta = u + u^{\perp}$ for some $u \in U , u^{\perp} \in U^{\perp}$ ( $U^{\perp}= \left \{ x |  \left \langle x , u \right \rangle = 0 \forall u \in U \right \}$) . Then :

$$d(\alpha,\beta + U) = |u^{\perp}| = \sqrt{ \left \langle u^{\perp} , u^{\perp} \right \rangle}$$

Using above lemma I write :

$$\alpha - \beta = u + u^{\perp}$$

$$u = \sum_{i=1}^{k} a_{i}\alpha_{i}$$

So the coefficients $a_{i}$ can be computed by Cramer rule :

$$a_{i} = \frac{G(\alpha_{1},...,\underset{i}{\alpha - \beta},...\alpha_{k})}{G(\alpha_{1},...\alpha_{k})}$$

Finally I need :

$$\left \langle G(0)\alpha_{0}+...+G(k)\alpha_{k},G(0)\alpha_{0}+...G(k)\alpha_{k} \right \rangle = G.G(0)$$

Here :

$$G(0) = G(\alpha_{1},...\alpha_{k})$$
$$\alpha - \beta = -a_{0}\alpha_{0},a_{0}=1$$
$$G(i) = a_{i}G(0)  \forall i \neq 0$$

Now I try hard to formulate two side of equality , and consider all permutation on $k$ elements and get the result . But this way seem very complicated .

I just want a shorter solution for this problem .